# How can I copy/paste text from one Vim file to another Vim file in another shell tab?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, vi

I understand copy/paste within Vim, but how can I copy/paste from one file open in Vim within one shell tab into another shell tab containing another open file?

A similar problem would be copying from a remote machine using Vim to a local machine.

Additional context: I am using a Raspberry Pi running [Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) GNU/Linux 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+clipboard

Comment: Though this doesn't solve your problem, you can try `:tabe file` to open another file in the same vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running in an X Window environment and you have `clipboard` support built into Vim, you can use the `+` register to yank and paste to/from the system clipboard.

For example, to yank a full line: `"+yy` and then to paste: `"+p`

For remote machines, I believe you would need to ssh in to the remote machine with X11 forwarding.